# How can I send two values through a select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to send the name and id field through the option tag. Right now as it is set up it is only sending id, how can send name as well to insert it in the data base?

```
<select name="category_id" size="1"><br />';

$sql = "SELECT id, name 
          FROM categories 
      ORDER BY name";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
}

echo'
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want category_id to be a multi-select or do you want it to be a single selection that returns both the ID and the name?

Comment: if you see the user will be able to see alist or options "name" all the values within the name field will be visible and the id of each value will be send through the option value. but I also want o send name. i think it could be a single selection that returns both the id and the name. Once the user select a name then it will insert id and name in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the option value have this format: `name$id`

```
<select name="category_id" size="1"><br />';

    $sql = "SELECT id, name 
              FROM categories 
          ORDER BY name";

    $rs = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
      echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."$".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
    }

    echo'
</select>
```

then when you retrieve the data you can explode it as so

```
$option = explode("$", $_POST['category_id']);
echo $option[0]; // Name
echo $option[1]; // Id
```

Comment: for the insert can I do this  $sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO products
(category, category_id)            
VALUES('$category', $category_id)";  to declare it I thinking about this $category = $option[0];  $category_id = $option[1];

Comment: Yes. `$sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO products (category, category_id) VALUES($option[0], $option[1])";` Assuming that name you gave is the category name.

Comment: O yes you nailed it right on the spot... Thanks. It took me sometime because I needed to edit something in the code to adjust your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a hidden `<input>` field and some javascript that writes the `<option>`'s text.

However, I can't think of a single application where that is desirable... The point of database normalization is to avoid duplication.

Comment: ok, Schwartzie has clarified it a single selection that returns both the ID and the name to the form method.